# Future migration of djangos permission system

Tags: python, django

I'm starting to use django and read a lot of documentation in the last days. I also read about the permission system as well as about other systems like django guardian package. I'm trying to implement a multi-user blogging system and I'm not sure if I shall use django permissions or something else, like django guardian. Is there a rule of thumbs? Is migrating easy (starting with standard permissions and later on something else).
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

From your description, you will need to use (something like) `django-guardian`.

Default Django permissions only apply to models(/tables). You cannot give someone permission to edit a specific article, category, comment or tag (only all articles, all categories, etc).